# Почему JLabel не может принять значение JTextField?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Reader extends JFrame{
    JButton b1,b2,b3;
    JLabel lk1,l2,l3,lk4,l5,l6,l7,l8,lk9,l10,l11,lk12,l13,lk14,lll;

    JTextField t1, t2,t3,t4,t5,t6;
    String b;

    String a;
    double x=0;
    double y=0;
    double i1=0;
    double i2=0;
    double i3=0;
    double i4=0;
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    public Reader(String s){
        super(s);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        b1=new JButton("VS");
        b2=new JButton("Удалить");
        b3=new JButton("Удалить");
        lk1=new JLabel("        "); 
        lll=new JLabel("                                ");
        l2=new JLabel("");
        l3=new JLabel("          Первый кот   ");
        lk4=new JLabel("                   ");
        l5=new JLabel("  Второй кот");
        l6=new JLabel("Имя");
        l7=new JLabel("Имя");
        l8=new JLabel("  Возраст");

        l10=new JLabel("Возраст");
        l11=new JLabel("   Вес");
        lk12=new JLabel("      ");
        l13=new JLabel("  Вес");
        lk14=new JLabel("");
        t1=new JTextField(6);
        t2=new JTextField(6);
        t3=new JTextField(4);
        t4=new JTextField(4);
        t5=new JTextField(4);
        t6=new JTextField(4);
        add(lk1);
        add(lll);
        add(l2);
        add(l3);
        add(b1);
        add(l5);
        add(l6);
        add(t1);

        add(l7);
        add(t2);
        add(l8);
        add(t3);

        add(l10);
        add(t4);
        add(l11);
        add(t5);
        add(lk12);
        add(l13);
        add(t6);
        add(b2);
        add(lk14);
        add(b3);
        b1.addActionListener(handler);
        b2.addActionListener(handler);
        b3.addActionListener(handler);
    }
    public class Handler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            try{
                if(e.getSource()==b3){
                    t2.setText(null);

                    t4.setText(null);

                    t6.setText(null);
                    l2.setText("");

                }
                if(e.getSource()==b2){
                    t1.setText(null);

                    t3.setText(null);

                    t5.setText(null);
                    l2.setText("");

                }
                if(e.getSource()==b1){
                    i1=Double.parseDouble(t3.getText());
                    if(i1<=3){
                        x=x-i1;
                    }
                    if(i1>3 && i1<10){
                        x=x+i1;
                    }
                    if(i1>10){
                        x=x-3;
                    }
                    i2=Double.parseDouble(t4.getText());

                    if(i2<=3){
                        y=y-i2;
                    }
                    if(i2>3 && i2<10){
                        y=y+i2;
                    }
                    if(i2>10){
                        y=y-3;
                    }
                    i3=Double.parseDouble(t5.getText());
                    i4=Double.parseDouble(t6.getText());
                    if(i3<4){
                        x=x-4;
                    }
                    if(i3>4 && i3<7){
                        x=x+i3;

                    }
                    if(i3>7){
                        x=x-3;
                    }
                    if(i4<4){
                        y=y-4;
                    }
                    if(i4>4 && i4<7){
                        y=y+i4;

                    }
                    if(i4>7){
                        y=y-3;
                    }

                    if(x>y){

                        a=t2+" победил!";//Вот тут ошибка
                        l2.setText(a);
                    }
                    if(x<y){
                        b=t1+" победил!";
                        l2.setText(b);
                    }
                    if(x==y){
                        l2.setText("Ничья!");
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"В поле Имя введите слово, а в полях Возраст и вес введите числа.");
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: `t2.getText()` потому что...

Comment: А можно поточнее?

Comment: @dhFarlast: ну, какого типа у вас `t2`?

Comment: JTextField вот..

Comment: @dhFarlast, ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с рекомендациями о том, [Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Можно пожалуйста ответить в чём ошибка поконкретнее?

Comment: Я вас очень прошу ткните меня носом где ошибка, и в чем она заключается

Comment: @dhFarlast: Так, и что тогда, по-вашему, компилятор должен сделать, увидев `t2 + " победил!"`? Сложить `JTextField` и строку?

Comment: @dhFarlast, Напишите свой вопрос, опишите проблему. А не просто скидывайте код и просите понять в чем проблема за вас!

Comment: @dhFarlast: И постарайтесь выкинуть из кода лишнее. Чем меньше кода, тем больше шансы на то, что участникам форума захочется читать ваш вопрос.

Comment: Я понимаю что это не правильно. Я учу программирование всего неделю и не могу найти как сделать то,что я хочу. Прошу помочь неучу

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятор пытается найти оператор сложения, который бы принял первым аргументом `JTextField`, и, очевидно, не находит. Складывать Java умеет только примитивные типы и строки.

Вы же явно хотите сделать:

```
a = t2.getText() + " победил";
l2.setText(a);
```

У `JTextField` есть метод `getText()`, который возвращает то, что вам нужно, — строку.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @dhFarlast отметьте ответ галкой, чтобы закрыть вопрос.